# NKAssetDownload not working on iPhone 5

Tags: ios6, download, nsurlconnection, iphone-5, newsstand-kit

I'm working on a newsstand app, and I'm having problems with NKAssetDownload, the downloads doesn't start after calling "downloadWithDelegate:".

The same app (code) works perfect on the simulator and on Iphone4 (all with ios6).

Any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: So, did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem myself.

Comment: Have you asked the Apple dev forums or Apple themselves through a DTS ticket about this?